# What was the first computer malware that could infect Mac systems?

Tags: apple-macintosh, malware

The number of malware that can infect Mac computers has increased significantly last decade (2010-2019), particularly scams (including tech support scams) and fake anti-malware apps. since when malware for Mac computers did exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first viruses for Mac were targeting Hypercard.  The first Hypercard virus appeared in about 1991.  Hypercard has a scripting language called HyperTalk, which was powerful enough to perform file-system accesses, thus allowing Hypercard viruses to discover and spread to other stacks (HyperCard "documents").

Comment: Raffzahn answer links to an Hypercard virus from 1988. Do you have a reference for 1991 being the first one?

Comment: Raffzahn is correct.  I forgot about Dukakis.  Three Tunes was 1991.

Answer (score 26):

The very first virus might have been

- **[nVir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVIR)** of 1987

Although technically not one, nVir worked much like a boot sector virus. Its source code did circulate on BBSes very soon after, leading to short flooding of copies. Still the damage was rather small. Not much later

- **[HyperAvenger](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=XE-ddYF6uhYC&pg=PT124&lpg=PT124&dq=hyperavenger%20macintosh&source=bl&ots=GhMMdoXPI0&sig=ACfU3U0zo4vHJ95sFZ9wANL9q-ATRYLbcQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM_N3l3-PnAhW7zMQBHS__ABsQ6AEwC3oECB4QAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)** of 1988 (also called Dukakis-Virus)

made its debut. It was based on [HyperCard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperCard) and became much more visible than nVir - after all, HyperCard was kind of a hype at the time.

During the mid 1990s a series of Word- and Excel-Macro virii did plague the Mac community.

Comment: I was involved in Mac support from about that time and nVir is the first one I remember encountering.

Comment: "Virii" is a plural for "virius" (if there were such a noun). Plural for "virus" in English is "viruses", see [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3838/55768).

Comment: @Ruslan Viri is the plural for vir, that's close ;P

Comment: It took years of therapy to be able to forget about the Office Macro virii. Years. 

Comment: It's a little mortifying to admit, but I wrote the Dukakis virus when I was 14. It was remarkably easy, once I'd had the idea... HyperCard let any program ("stack") freely modify the script of the "home stack". Script in the home stack would run when any other stack started up, and it could then freely modify the script of that stack, etc...